# IBM Worklight 6.0 Android App crash on startup after update

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Worklight 6.0 to develop an Android Application.

I recently published an update on Google Play, and I found multiple crash reports like this one :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.worklight.common.WLUtils.getTree(WLUtils.java:558)
at com.worklight.common.WLUtils.getTree(WLUtils.java:553)
at com.worklight.common.WLUtils.computeChecksumOnExternal(WLUtils.java:537)
at com.worklight.common.WLUtils.checksumTestOnResources(WLUtils.java:421)
at com.worklight.androidgap.WLDroidGap.testResourcesChecksum(WLDroidGap.java:162)
at com.worklight.androidgap.WLDroidGap.doPrepareAssetsWork(WLDroidGap.java:684)
at com.worklight.androidgap.WLDroidGap.access$500(WLDroidGap.java:65)
at com.worklight.androidgap.WLDroidGap$PrepareClientAsyncTask.doInBackground(WLDroidGap.java:716)
at com.worklight.androidgap.WLDroidGap$PrepareClientAsyncTask.doInBackground(WLDroidGap.java:712)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 3 more
```

It's my last update since more than 10 months, and I am using an updated Worklight (6.0) studio version that I installed about two months ago.

This error occures on startup, and on multiple Android versions (I've seen crashes on 4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4 2.3) using multiple phones (Galaxy S5, S4, Xperia Z1, Z2, LG G3, HTC One ...)

This error happens for some users, and for them it happens every time.

This error happens only for users who already have the app and make an update.

Cleaning app cache let the app work again.

This crash happen right away on startup.

Does any one have this issue, or know how to fix it?

Is this a Worklight issue?

Comment: Does the error happen all the time? does the error happen when the app is already installed and then being replaced with this new version, or a fresh-new installation? Does it happen right away or after a while?

Comment: @IdanAdar edited the question with answers : happens all the time for some users - happens only with app already installed then updated - happens right away

Comment: Can you try to recreate this crash with a *new*  app > upload to google play > install on device > create new version > upload to google play > update app on device > crash / no crash?

Comment: Do you have an AsyncTask doing something in your application?

Comment: @IdanAdar I cannot recreate the crash with the scenario you described because : 1- the crash does not happens for all users but only for few of them. 2- the old version was created using an old Worklight 6.0 version, and the updated one is created using a new Worklight 6.0 version.

Comment: @DanielA.González the app is using Worklight framework, and my code is purely HTML5 / JS with no android java code, except Cordova and Worklight libs. So I don't have AsyncTask in my code, but may be Worklight use it.

Comment: Ok, I just see that it is failing and I wasn't sure if it was your code or something in Cordova/Worklight.

Comment: Do you know in what part of your code it is failing? Is it on init or somewhere else?

Comment: @WiPhone, the latest iFixes for Worklight 6.0 contain fixes for crahes that happened on app init after updating it; perhaps this also covers your scenario -- update to the latest iFix and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: I confirm that the last fix solves the crash issue, but I have noticed after update a different issue in another app as explained at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508604/ibm-worklight-6-0-error-on-android-app-launch

Comment: @WiPhone, if this specific question is resolved, please mark as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

This application crash upon init after updating it is resolved by applying the latest available Worklight 6.0.0.x iFix, as confirmed by the user in the comments.

The latest Worklight 6.0.0.x iFix can be obtained from [IBM Fix Central](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/).